# longest substring without repeatition bruteforce algorithm error leetcode

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, brute-force

I have tried a whole day still answer is not coming. I don't know how to find whether an element exists in the vector or not other than this `std::find(substr.begin(),substr.end(),s[j]) != substr.end()` technique.
see my code :

```cpp
class Solution {
    public:
        int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        int max_length = 0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            int temp = 0;
            for(int j=i;j<s.length();j++){
                
                vector<char> substr;
                
                //char ele = s[j];
                if(substr.empty()){
                    substr.push_back(s[j]);
                    temp++;
                    
                }
                else if( std::find(substr.begin(),substr.end(),s[j]) != substr.end()){
                    substr.push_back(s[j]);
                    temp++;
                    cout<<j<<" iteration "<<temp<<endl;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            //cout<<temp<<endl;
            max_length = max(temp,max_length);
        }
        
    return max_length;
    }
};
```

question is  Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

**Example 1:**

Input: s = "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
Example 2:

Input: s = "bbbbb"
Output: 1
Explanation: The answer is "b", with the length of 1.
Example 3:

Input: s = "pwwkew"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "wke", with the length of 3.
Notice that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.
Example 4:

Input: s = ""
Output: 0

here my temp is not increasing because of that else if condition `(std::find(substr.begin(),substr.end(),s[j]) != substr.end())` is not working as expected.

**pseudocode:**

1. for each letter greater than i take vector store subsequent non repetitive letters into that vector and then increase temp
2. if you found a letter which is present in vector then break out of the loop
3. compare if its greater than max if yes replace max if no continue with all other letters.

ps: I'm a noob in coding and this is my first question. Help me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Most of these questions on leetcode already have detailed answers to them you could check them out

Comment: how is `std::find(substr.begin(),substr.end(),s[j]) != substr.end())` not working as expected? What did you expect, what happens instead?

Comment: you have to pay attention to the scope of the vector. You declared it inside the loop, hence you either insert an element or you try to find an element in it. And then on the next iteration you get a new empty vector

Comment: `vector<char> substr; if(substr.empty()){` this condition can never be `false`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i wanted this **std::find(substr.begin(),substr.end(),s[j]) != substr.end())**  to return true if there is no same element inside the vector i.e it should return true if s[j] is 'a' and 'a' is not present in vector substr.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i rectified  what you said about scope of vector and **vector<char> substr; if(substr.empty()){** still the main problem I don't know how to check whether an element is present in the vector or not? so please help me with that if you know. thanks for helping

Comment: your usage of `std::find` is correct.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 so do you have any idea why It might not be working

Comment: i already told you: You create a new vector on each iteration. This vector is empty, you add one element and on the next iteration you get a new vector.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i did but i couldn't get the answer so I rewrote the code using map instead of vector and it worked. anyways thanks for helping. Btw I'm new to this so can you say how change background of something like code in your comment like std::find or how you highlight those things